# matrix transposition during Euclidean distance

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

I'm trying to follow along with an online class that's using matrix vectorization for image comparison.  Although I have the solution, I don't understand one of the matrix transformations. This is probably basic linear algebra, but I'm decades removed from my last math class. The problem is roughly:

> Given a matrix **A** that is `500x7000`, and a matrix **B** that is
>   `5000x7000`, we want to take the Euclidean distance for each row of
>   **A** with respect to each row of **B**.
>
> The result should be a distance matrix **D**, with shape `500x5000`.

The point of the exercise is to learn how to do vectorized comparisons (using numpy), vs the obvious programmatic approach of looping over **A**, then looping over **B** to take their differences. The tricky part here is that **A** and **B** have a different number of rows.

We're given hints to expand the formula for Euclidean distance, i.e. $$\sqrt{\sum{(A-B)^2}}$$ This expands to $$\sqrt{\sum{A^2 + B^2 -2AB}}$$

The first two terms are manageable- element-wise squaring and summation. But for the third term, we need to multiply A by B, and since they have different row counts, some manipulation is needed. The solution is to use: $$-2A \cdot B^T$$

That is, the dot product of A with B transposed (maybe I got the formatting wrong here?) This works, and I get the expected answer. But I'm not satisfied that the math is "correct".

**My question**: if we are transposing B, doesn't that mean that the "wrong" numbers are multiplied with A? I understand that a transpose essentially flips the numbers around its axis, so this seems like an artificial way to simply make the rows/cols line up conveniently. Obviously this works, but it seems wrong to me. Help me understand why this works, mathematically.

Comment: Careful, if $A$ and $B$ are matrices (which, a priori, do not commute), $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2 + AB + BA$ and what would be the meaning of $\sqrt{(A-B)^2}$ ?

Comment: You're right, the radical makes no sense the way I wrote it. I meant to say the square root of the sum of the squares of the difference. Let's see if I can get the syntax right: $$\sqrt{\sum{(A-B)^2}}$$